# Wrapping up a QLabel in a QWidget to make it act like an enum with an image

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I have a label on my MainWindow and I am setting the RichText to be a static image that comes from my resource file. This works great, but I want to abstract away the fact that this is a label and expose a single method called `SetImage(std::string path);` so I can make this work more like an enumeration of images.

Thinking about it, if I wanted to do something like this irrespective of a framework or image, my feeling would be to contain a label inside a class to abstract away the fact that I'm using a label in this way.

So, I would have something like this in QT:

```
class QMyWidget : public QWidget {
public:
  explicit QMyWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
  virtual ~QMyWidget();
  SetImage(const std::string& path);
private:
   QLabel* m_label;
};
```

and then calling SetImage would do something like

```
QMyWidget::SetImage(const std::string& path){
   //setup label for rich text;
   std::string richText("//format rich text string here to load the image resource");
   m_label->SetText(richText);
};
```

Is this the right way to go about this, or is there a better, more "QT" way to solve this problem? I'm trying to avoid doing a bunch of heavy lifting in the designer or something like that.

Comment: It's fine. Although I would use `QString` for this.

Comment: Why would you use QLabel for this instead of QImage?

Comment: Qimage is a better option for sure. I had come across QLabel being easy for static images and didn't research any further. I'll go the QImage route

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution to hide the implementation details.

You may also consider using QImage or at least one of the image classes instead of QLabel though.

Also, the method is spelled as [setText](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qlabel.html#text-prop), not `SetText` on it.

Also, a minot nitpick, but in a Qt project, you may want to use QString instead of std::string in case the name is not ascii, but utf.

Another nitpick, mark your destructor with `override` and make it `= default`.

Also, use a more meaningful name than `QMyWidget`.

As a matter of preference of mine, I would also not leave the `Q_OBJECT` out in the class. It may not be required now, but it can always help with debugging, when you add signals and slots, etc, and then it can cause headaches why things do not work.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback. I was doing my best to add a minimal reproducible example. QMyWidget is not my actual class name, and setText was just me typing it in to my post by memory.